# Having trouble with toFixed()

Tags: javascript, html, tofixed

I'm just putting together a basic interest calculator and I'm trying to use toFixed(2) to limit   the result to two decimal places, but I can't seem to figure out the proper spot to include it. All my attempts so far either cause the slider to no longer be responsive or clicking the button no longer provides the result. I would really appreciate some guidance.

Here's Code

```js
function compute() {
  //variables for the operation
  var principal = document.getElementById("principal").value;
  var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value;
  var years = document.getElementById("years").value;
  var interest = principal * years * rate / 100;
  var year = new Date().getFullYear() + parseInt(years);

  //if else statement to validate operation
  if (principal == undefined || principal <= 0) {
    alert("Enter a positive number");
    document.getElementById("principal").focus();
    return
  } else {
    var inr = "If you deposit <mark>" + "$" + principal + "</mark><br>";
    var ra = "at an interest rate of <mark>" + rate + "%</mark><br>";
    var am = "You will receive an amount of <mark>" + "$" + interest + "</mark><br>";
    var ye = "in the year <mark'>" + year + "</mark>";

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = inr + ra + am;
  }
}

function updateRate() {
  var rateval = document.getElementById("rate").value;
  document.getElementById("rate_val").innerText = rateval;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title> Simple Interest Calculator</title>
  <script src="js/simpleinterestcalc.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simpleinterestcalc.css">
</head>
<div class="maindiv">
  <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>

  Amount <input type="number" id="principal"> <br/> Rate <input type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="20" step="0.01" value="10.25" onchange=u pdateRate()>
  <span id="rate_val">10.25</span><span>%</span> <br/> No. of Years
  <select id="years">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select> <br/>
  <span id="result"></span><br>

  <button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
</div>
<footer>

  &#169; This Calculator belongs to -- Jake B --


</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: The only error I see is that caused by using HTML attributes to attach event listeners: `onchange=u pdateRate()>` The extra space causes an uncaught ReferenceErrror: u is not defined to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Change `interest` to `interest.toFixed(2)` when you're creating the output string.

```
    var am = "You will receive an amount of <mark>" + "$" + interest.toFixed(2) + "</mark><br>";
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to apply the toFixed while calculating the interest

```
var interest = (principal * years * rate / 100).toFixed(2); // Limit to two decimal places
```

There are several reasons why I recommend to avoid applying the `toFixed(2)` during string concatenation

1. Templates have a tendency to get complex, and removing logic for them helps to keep them tidy.
2. You might want to use the interest in other places in the code and it's important to keep it consistent.